# Why aren't the points to the left and right of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, respectively, nodes?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

What I don't get is by the definition of a node -- a point where two or more circuit elements join -- it appears that the dots to the left and right of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are nodes; both of those points join the dependent voltage source with a resistor, as I understand it.

Comment: Who/what said they aren't nodes?

Comment: Nodes in what sense? When you see it as lumped elements, you can draw R1 directly to node a and nothing changes.

Comment: I'm looking at an answer key that does not identify them as nodes, but identifies a-f as nodes (which makes sense to me). Nodes in the sense that a node is defined as a point joining two or more circuit elements.

Comment: The dot to the left of \$R_1\$ is node a, the dot to the right of \$R_2\$ is node e.

Comment: Everything that is joined together with a wire is one (and only one) node. The nodes you mention are the same as a and e.

Comment: The reason I don't understand those being described as identical is because the nodes join different components.

By the way, thank you guys so much for the response, this is my first time on the Electronics Stack Exchange. Posted this too soon accidentally, but I still don't understand and am taking a moment to figure it out.

Comment: You could redraw it with a star configuration and the wires joining at one point. It should be invariant with that sort of manipulation.

Comment: Don't take the word "point" too literally. The dots aren't nodes, they just indicate connection of wires. All the wires that are connected (without components in-between) are part of the same node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are nodes `a` and `e` respectively.

Node `a` connects R1, R3, R6, and two unnamed current sources.
Node `e` connects R2, R5, a current source and a voltage source.

Trace ALL the wires out from a node name until you reach a component : don't just stop when you reach an anonymous dot.